# How do I get an iOS vector image without aliasing?

Tags: ios, image, pdf, svg, xamarin.ios

So I added my images as vector PDFs to the assets since I thought this should get me the highest quality. But when I actually use them as button images they show up very aliased:

[image: image with aliasing]

But if I replace the vector PDFs with PNGs the size of 50x50px for 2x and 100x100px for 3x, I get a perfect image without any aliasing:

[image: image without aliasing]

But why is this? Is there any way to get the vector image smoother? And if not why would you use vector images at all?

Btw, my code is nothing special I just set the button image somewhat like this, but in Xamarin.Ios:

`myBtn.setImage( UIImage.init(named: "imagename"), for: .selected)`

Also note that the reason the white background isn't there in the second image is, because I removed it when I created the PNGs.

Comment: Have you tried: In your assets catalog select your PDF image, then on the inspector pane (right one), check the box 'Preserve Vector Data'.

Comment: @LouisLac this is indeed the solution. But because I am using Xamarin.iOS I wasn't able to set it, since Visual Studio doesn't provide that option. Maybe you can create an answer for this, so I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: @DerSeegler Hi , if have solved it , remember later to mark the answer .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Xcode in your assets catalog select your PDF image, then on the inspector pane (right one), check the box 'Preserve Vector Data'.

It could be hidden when using Xamarin.iOS, documentation can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=macos#Using-Vector-Images-in-Asset-Catalogs).

Comment: Since its hidden when using Xamarin.iOS, the following line has to be added to the properties section in the Contents.json of each Asset: `"preserves-vector-representation": true`